# Getting Bad Certificate Error while SSl Hand shake Expcetion

Tags: java, ssl

After installing the Verisign Certificate we are getting the BAD Certificate Error, 
Same server works fine on Self Signed Certificate..
Please help me how to fix this error.

6/17/15 23:56:29:493 PDT] 0000001c SystemErr     R ***javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: bad certificate***
        at com.ibm.jsse.bv.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jsse.bv.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.o(b.java:136)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.i.connect(i.java:28)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.http.bc.getOutputStream(bc.java:44)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.l.getOutputStream(l.java:23)
        at com.corio.tsr.webservices.SRAutomationWebServiceClient.getJsonObject(SRAutomationWebServiceClient.java:174)
        at com.corio.tsr.jms.receiver.SRAutomationMessageBean.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invokeMdbMethod(MessageEndpointHandler.java:1013)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointHandler.java:746)
        at $Proxy1.onMessage(Unknown Source)

Above is the error logs which are genarated during the SSL Hand Shake.

Following steps have been tried to fix this.
1) Importing the certificates to the server side (cacertsfile)

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is this web service client running standalone, or deployed under WebSphere? This will help in deciding the next steps to debug the problem. There are many reasons an SSL Handshake might fail.

Answer (score 1):

A bad certificate error would typically be due to missing signer certificates.  On a handshake the server will present it's personal certificate.  This certificate must be trusted so the trust store is examined for the signers.  In the case of a self signed certificate the self signed certificate is it's own signer.  So that personal certificate should be in the trust store.  For a Verisign certificate (or any CA) the personal certificate is usually signed by one or more intermediate certificates and a root.  These signers need to be in the trust store to avoid the bad certificate error.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the cacerts file is corrupt while importing ?

Can u paste the console log when importing was done ? May be you can backup the current cacerts file and start with using a pristine jdk cacerts file.

Also, Check the certificates in the cert store file

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/keytool -v -list -keystore <cert-file-full-path>
```